# Azure API Management responses 404

Tags: rest, azure, asp.net-web-api

I've created simple Web API using Microsoft Azure. When I make simple call by link http://taskswebapp.azurewebsites.net/api/tasks/ it returns JSON string properly.
Than I've created Azure API Management with following settings:

- Web service URL: http://taskswebapp.azurewebsites.net/
- Web API URL suffix: api

And new operation:

- HTTP verb*: GET
- URL template: /tasks

When I try to make this call on API Management Developers Portal, it responses 404.

> Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location:
>   https://apimgmtstep0m850qbbqfy1r.blob.core.windows.net/apiinspectorcontainer/N8BZ_bvg_tqqEKKM3-9CFg2-26?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=LOoq%2Bpp%2B8TMgiAzir%2BqxrZv4WsVN6LeVg1bR%2Fjjh0ag%3D&se=2015-10-19T11%3A47%3A22Z&sp=r&traceId=1b3f1ff48b5d400799b497337e299213
>   Date: Sun, 18 Oct 2015 11:47:22 GMT Set-Cookie:
>   ARRAffinity=47ee33511877c67ac64671db4dc13c4d3d30ad6daa9c461e9a39036fc4112292;Path=/;Domain=taskswebapp.azurewebsites.net
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 103 Content-Type: text/html
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Service URL should be http://taskswebapp.azurewebsites.net/api

Web API URL suffix is the suffix for the public facing URL (i.e., foo.azure-api.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for 404 can be an incorrectly defined route in the frontend section.

e.g. /resource is fine while /resource/ will lead to a 404.

This can easily happen if you work with path variables, because the initial frontend route value has to be corrected (it puts some variable stuff there)